Data Validation Loop + Export To PDF
I am trying to get a macro to run that will cycle through a Data Validation list on cell C6 and with each list option selected, it exports to PDF.
The list macro I have will cycle the list, and export like it is supposed to however it will not load the data on the page and thus exports a blank PDF. The values will change monthly and the list pulls from a secondary sheet.
The 3 sheets I have in the workbook are: 'Sorted Data', 'Quarterly Data', and 'Data Validation'.
Data Validation has 2 DV lists that pull from data on the Quarterly Data sheet.
Data Validation Sheet
(I do need Company listed as I need a total of all numerical units)
Quarterly Data is where the report ran will be copy and pasted
Quarterly Data Sheet
The Sorted Data sheet has a drop down on C6. This is what I need to cycle. When I manually cycle, the cells/formulas below pull the data accurately. The macro will list the data when it changes to Company, but will show data when it cycles to a unit number.
Macro-Company View
Macro-Unit View
I believe it has to do with how it is inputting the unit number, as the macro has the numerical formatted to the right, however when manually selecting it stays formatted centered
Unit-Manual Selection
Any assistance here would be greatly appreciated.
This is the code I have so far:
Public Sub Create_PDF_For_Each_Company()

    Dim DVrange As Range
    Dim companyValues As Variant, company As Variant
    
    With ActiveSheet
        Set DVrange = Range(.Range("C6").Validation.Formula1)
        With DVrange.Worksheet
            companyValues = .Range(DVrange(1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, DVrange.Column).End(xlUp)).Value
        End With
        For Each company In companyValues
            .Range("C6").Value = company
            .ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:="C:\Users\457158\Desktop\Export Macro Test\" & company & ".pdf", _
                Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
        Next
    End With

End Sub


Are the Company values on your Data Validation sheet formatted as Text?  What formatting is applied on C6?

When I go to formatting (CTRL+1) it is General
When I select the drop down and select a unit number, it gives me the ! in a triangle that says "The number in the cell is formatted as text or is preceded by an apostrophe."
The data validation sheet for column A (where the list pulls from) is also formatted as general. The numbers are listed out from the Quarterly Data sheet with this formula
=SORT(UNIQUE(FILTER('Quarterly Data'!$D$2:$D$5000, 'Quarterly Data'!$D$2:$D$5000 <>"")))

I just formatted the List and the Data Validation sheet to Number, when I run the macro it has the formatting the same as manual selection(Centered) but still doesnt load the data for Unit numbers, only for the Company input

How exactly does changing the company number trigger an update to the list below?

The cells are IFs, COUNTIFS, SUMIFS, etc that all pull data from Quarterly Data sheet based on Cell C6(unit number) - the state one for example is  --- =IF($C$6 <> "Company", UNIQUE(FILTER('Quarterly Data'!$I$2:$I$5000, 'Quarterly Data'!$D$2:$D$5000 = 'Sorted Data'!$C$6, "")), SORT(UNIQUE(FILTER('Quarterly Data'!$I$2:$I$5000, 'Quarterly Data'!$D$2:$D$5000 <>  "", ""))))

The rest are a version of (varying from SUMIF and COUNTIF and the criteria based on the column)   --- =IF($A10<>"", IF($C$6 <> "Company", SUMIFS('Quarterly Data'!$M$2:$M$5000, 'Quarterly Data'!$D$2:$D$5000, 'Sorted Data'!$C$6, 'Quarterly Data'!$I$2:$I$5000, 'Sorted Data'!$A10, 'Quarterly Data'!$K$2:$K$5000, "DEFD"), SUMIFS('Quarterly Data'!$M$2:$M$5000, 'Quarterly Data'!$I$2:$I$5000, 'Sorted Data'!$A10, 'Quarterly Data'!$K$2:$K$5000, "DEFD")),"")

Have you tried calculating the sheet after changing the value in C6?  "exports a blank PDF" - presumably not completely blank - it has the headers for the listing?  The data in your source table has the company number formatted as text, so likely you need to match that in C6.

The macro changes the value in C6 then runs the export, then changes value and runs export, rinse and repeat. It leaves the top sections in, it is just not pulling the data over on the formula cells, except for when Company is listed. If I manually change the list, it loads the formulas correctly and will export to PDF accurately.
